# How to fix Cannot open source file: 'seal/util/config.h'

Tags: c++, seal

I am currently using VS studio 2019 and cloned from GIT MicrosoftSEAL using Visual Studio i am having problems making it run.

I already downloaded C++ packages along with SDK 10.0.16299.0 then retargetted the whole projects but still getting the 34 errors (1 E196 and 33 C0183) from a file called mscv.h which has the include line underlined

```
// Read in config.h
#include "seal/util/config.h"
```

Errors:

```
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "seal/util/config.h"

Error   C1083    Cannot open include file: 'seal/util/config.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where is Seal installed? Where is the header files installed? Are the header files installed in a *standard* location where the compiler looks by default? Perhaps you need to modify the project settings so that the compiler will look at the directory where the Seal header files are installed?

Comment: Does this file exist (seal/util/config.h)?

Comment: well i can find a seal/util/config,h.in

Comment: Seal is installed on the default place visual studio gave me

Comment: There were earlier some issues with SEAL not working properly on Visual Studio 2019 but these have been fixed recently. What version of SEAL are you using? Maybe try pulling again (master branch) and see if it works.

Comment: i was able to make it work by manually cmake-ing the CMakeList.txt so far i have yet to encounter any errors